# Firebird 2.5.6 romanian collation for UTF8 charset

Tags: sql, utf-8, firebird, collation

I have a table in Firebird 2.5.6. It has the `UTF8` charset and contains Romanian characters. However, when I want to order the characters by Romanian logic, the result is wrong.

An example of this issue can be found below:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
  ID INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  TXT VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET UTF8 DEFAULT '-' NOT NULL COLLATE UTF8,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Assuming I insert the following rows:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, TXT) VALUES (1, 'S');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, TXT) VALUES (2, 'SA');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, TXT) VALUES (3, 'Ș');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, TXT) VALUES (4, 'ȘA');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, TXT) VALUES (5, 'T');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, TXT) VALUES (6, 'TA');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, TXT) VALUES (7, 'Ț');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, TXT) VALUES (8, 'ȚA');
```

When I run the following query, the result is not what i would expect.

```
select id, txt from test order by txt
```

returns:

```
ID  TXT
1   S
2   SA
5   T
6   TA
3   Ș
4   ȘA
7   Ț
8   ȚA
```

But the correct ordering for Romanian is:

```
ID  TXT
1   S
2   SA
3   Ș
4   ȘA
5   T
6   TA
7   Ț
8   ȚA
```

Can this be done without changing the charset from `UTF8` ?

Comment: Maybe `order by txt collate UNICODE` works. As far as I can see there is no special romanian collation available.

Comment: The standard unicode collation is a generic unicode sort, not Romanian. You will need to create a Romania-specific collation, and this may require you to replace the ICU library with another version (as the one shipped with Firebird on Windows does not contain the full ICU set). Unfortunately, the [collation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-collation.html) documentation of Firebird is rather lacking in detail.

Comment: As an example the command should be something like `create collation utf8_ro for utf8 from UNICODE 'locale=ro'`, but it will likely fail due to the limited ICU lib shipped with Firebird, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449451/create-collation-of-firebird3-0-1-db-error-on-windows-but-succeed-on-centos

Answer (score 0):

(This answer may not apply; it refers to MySQL collations.)

Unicode defines a general collation that tends to be "wrong" in some way for every language.  You have hit such.

Switch to `utf8_romanian_ci` to the the ordering you desire.  That `COLLATION` has been available in MySQL for, I think, at least a decade.

Note the distinction between these two letters:  `Ș` and `Ş`

```
C59E        350=x015E  [Ş]    L  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CEDILLA
C898        536=x0218  [Ș]    L  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH COMMA BELOW
```

I point out [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) that `utf8_romanian_ci` (also polish and turkish) correctly sorts `Ş`, but my list fails to list the other flavor of S.

Answer (score 0):

By the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference, you have to use character set UTF8 with collation UTF8, which supports all the languages supported by the Unicode 4.0.

If your db is for use only in your country, you better adopt character set ISO8859_2 with the same-named collation, being only 1byte-per-character wide instead of 4 bytes for UTF8.